# Проверка строки по регулярному выражению

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, что не так делаю:

Есть строки вида:
1000x100
1000x10000

Нужно сделать проверку данной строки, чтобы ни одна из чисел до или после "x" не была меньше 100 и больше 10000.

Чтобы получить true от 100x100 до 9999x9999.

Пробую так:

```
/^(\d+){3,4}x(\d+){3,4}$/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался, вот что получилось в итоге.

```
/^[1-9](\d){3,4}x[1-9](\d){3,4}$/
```

Comment: 101x102 не сработает,  т.к. в числах 101 и 102 только 3 символа, а первый из них вы жестко задали [1-9]

Comment: ах да, поправил, спс за замечание )

Comment: омг

    ^(\d{3,4})x(\d{3,4})$

Comment: тогда уж так

    /^([1-9]\d{2,3})x([1-9]\d{2,3})$/

Answer (score 0):

Разве не так?
    /\d+/g

Answer (score 0):

При вводе 0001x0010 ваша программа вылетет с ошибкой? Насколько помню, в регулярках нельзя прикрутить условный оператор. Поэтому просто берите число (в этом регулярка помочь сможет) и проверяйте программно.

Comment: я никаких ошибок не наблюдаю при проверки строки  0001x0010. Выводит true, мне же просто чекнуть надо. Кстати 0001x0010 такие значения тоже нельзя пропускать.
Можно конечно взять два значения проверить их по отдельности, просто я хотел сделать все за раз, одну проверку. Попробую ее помучиться, может что получится.

С нулевым числом в начале строки разобрался так

    /^[1-9](\d+){3,4}x[1-9](\d+){3,4}$/